# How to compress the responses to reduce page weight in .net

Tags: .net, compression, rendering

Can anyone suggest the ways we can choose to reduce the size of the rendered html 
or response to reduce page weight in .net so that the client can experience a faster loading of the UI

i've heard of JSON and GZip

but don't have much idea about how to use it or even better ways are there

Answer (score 0):

Without programming - GZIP compression of the output. This is a module in IIS 7 that you (or the hister) installs (one for static, one for dynamic content) and that then gets simply activated in the configuration for a website.

Probably the most efficient thing.

Answer (score 0):

GZip is a standard way to do this, you can find more information about doing this in .NET [here](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/10564.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from GZip, which has already been mentioned (JSON doesn't have anything to do with this), you can minify your javascript and css files. It might not be as effective as enabling GZIP, but it can still greatly descrease the size of these files, which is especially helpfull when you have many, or large files.

There's an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/combineMinify.aspx), which is based on ASP.NET MVC, but if you look around you will find some tutorials for classic WebForms as well.

Comment: Is there any other method other than GZip (Without programming)

Comment: Not for IIS as far as I know. There are GZip alternatives out there for maybe Apache, but I don't know them and wonder why you would use them over GZip.

Comment: k Thank you..

Actually I was doing R&D work.. Wanted to do some comparative study.

But now it is like.. nothing is there to compare with GZip